# How to update all values in a column with a single Update query?

Tags: sql

I have a database table where I want to update all values in a column with a single update command. suppose I have a table TEST with having a column CITY,I want to update all values in City column with one value. What is the Query?
if city has values like: sydney, brooklyn, manhatton then update command replace all these values with manhatton.

Comment: What do you want to update it to?

Comment: That's precisely what `UPDATE` does if you don't specify a `WHERE` filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to update all rows in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635689/efficient-way-to-update-all-rows-in-a-table)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do a blanket `UPDATE`, specifying no restrictions on which records to update:

```
UPDATE TEST
SET CITY = 'New Value'
```