# How can I update a table and set a column to be equal to It's ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have the table Product with 3000 products.

I have the ID auto increment as primary key
Also have the column barcode

How can I set the barcode to be the same as the product ID for everyone?

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you show some sample data here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to update all rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635689/efficient-way-to-update-all-rows-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Product
SET Barcode = ID
```

Comment: I think I would shudder if I saw someone executing a query like this in production.

Comment: So would I, but that seems to do what he's asking.  I'm paranoid, so any time I write an update statement I always start it with `WHERE 1=2` So I don't accidentally run it on all.

Comment: Fair enough...didn't mean to discredit the correctness of your answer :-)

Comment: @ChrisAllwein You could use SSMS add-ins like SSMS  Boost (Fatal Action Guard) It is really helpful when you select only part of update/delete query :) and hit run.

Comment: That did what I needed, sorry im beginner yet
Why does it looks like a bad query?

Comment: @ChrisAllwein I usually like to run with rollback and output the changes (deleted.column | inserted.column) to a temp table to see what will actually change.  It gives a good visual and validation.

Comment: @JohnC Because you are changing every row identifier in your table. Every reference you have to a product ID will become invalid. (foreign keys for instance).